# How to disable editing for guest (i.e. not authenticated users) in DokuWiki?

Tags: permissions, dokuwiki

I have noticed that by default, after installation, DokuWiki allows everybody to edit and delete pages, even people who don't have a DokuWiki account. I know that there is are settings that allow you to disable specific actions, but as far as I can tell, those disable the related actions even to authenticated users.

So, is there a way to edit guest users permissions in DokuWiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so apparently there is no "guest" user group in DokuWiki, however you can user other built-in groups to work around this: under **Administration > Access Control List Manager**, give Read permissions to the @ALL group (authenticated and not authenticated users), and Upload (or whatever you need) to the @user group (only authenticated users).

[image]